# Как правильно задать строку подключения к БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

Как правильно задать строку подключения к локальной БД так, чтобы каждый раз вручную не менять путь?

Есть такая строка подключения:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LibraryModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LibraryModel.csdl|res://*/LibraryModel.ssdl|res://*/LibraryModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\LibrarySystem.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Строка подключения была создана автоматически. Если запускать мой проект с такой вот строкой подключения, то возникает исключение в программе:

Внутреннее исключение 1:
SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Cuurjol\Desktop\123\BACKUP LIBRARY\Library\Library\bin\Debug\LibrarySystem.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Я в интернете долго искал решение этой проблемы, нашёл, нужно вместо attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\LibrarySystem.mdf писать целиком весь путь к файлу, ну например так:

```
attachdbfilename=C:\Users\Cuurjol\Desktop\123\BACKUP LIBRARY\Library\Library\LibrarySystem.mdf
```

Но я так не хочу писать путь, поскольку папка с проектом может быть располагаться где угодно, а мне нужно как-то в App.config написать так, чтобы всегда было подключение к БД вне зависимости от расположения самого проекта на жёстком диске.

Как это можно сделать? И почему всё-таки сгенерированная строка подключения к БД не работает при запуске проекта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задать относительный путь к БД с помощью подстановочной переменной |DataDirectory|, конечно, можно. Ее значение зависит от типа проекта:

- Для обычного настольного приложения - путь к папке с EXE-файлом
- Для приложения ClickOnce - путь к специальной папке данных
- Для ASP.NET приложений - путь к папке App_Data

Можно переопределить значение в коде:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", newpath)
```

См. [данную статью](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/08/26/working-with-local-databases/), [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings).

Что касается ошибки *An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ... failed.*, у нее может быть много причин. Файл не существует, у учетной записи службы SQL не хватает прав, чтобы его открыть, БД с таким именем уже существует и т.п. Обычно использовать свойство `AttachDbFileName`, тем более с автогенерированным именем БД - не лучшая практика. Лучше создать программу или скрипт развертывания, который будет однократно присоединять БД с явно заданным именем, а в программе задать свойство `Initial Catalog`. Так будет куда проще обслуживать программу.