# Как указать путь к local db из папки проекта

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, visual-studio, sql-server-localdb

Есть приложение windows forms для работы с базой данных. Делал для универа. Теперь нужно скинуть папку с проектом преподавателю, но не могу изменить путь к localbd базе данных. Он указывает на мой локальный диск, а нужно чтоб указывал на папку проекта, чтоб проект был переносимым.Нужно что то сделать со строкой connection string. Спасите мой курсач! Заранее спасибо

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Installed\VS Projects\DataBaseApp\DataBaseApp\DataBaseMusicShop.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

        SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Product]", sqlConnection);
        try
        {
            sqlReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["id_product"]) + "  " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["p_firm"]) + "  " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["p_type"]) + "  " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["p_price"]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.Source.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlReader != null)
                sqlReader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите для начала: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776652/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%91%D0%94/777174#777174

Comment: Строка соединения должна быть в конфиге. Там её можно легко изменить без перекомпиляции проекта. Строка в конфиге меняется либо инсталлятором на этапе установки вашего приложения, либо, если инсталляции как таковой нет, при первом запуске приложение запрашивает путь к базе (и сохраняет его). Или же просто: открываете конфиг в любом текстовом редакторе и меняете строку соединения на нужную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используй `|DataDirectory|` - это путь откуда запускаешь приложение.
Может возникнуть ситуация при запуске программы из VisualStudio, при сборке приложение попадает в папку Debug/Release, но файл БД например в проекте твоем.
Установи файлу БД свойство -> копировать всегда

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBaseMusicShop.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]